# Line chart marker value label switching up and down

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

Is there a clever way to place label indicating value above marker, for next point below marker and so on like:

`(62.2% above, 71.6% below, 77.3% above, 84.9% below...)`

[image]

I know that I can manually place each label but I search for automatic way to achieve it.

Maybe some kind of settings/formula/VBA macro?

Comment: vba/macro can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this macro:

```
Public Sub alternateLabels()

      Dim ch As Chart
      Dim lab As DataLabel
      Dim s As Series
      Dim count As Integer

  ' use the appropriate names for the objects and worksheets here
      Set ch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart

  ' this should be the "cumulative" series, check with msgbox, and remove msgbox line if it's ok
      Set s = ch.SeriesCollection(2)
      MsgBox s.Name 'remove this line as needed

      For Each lab In s.DataLabels
          If count Mod 2 = 0 Then
              lab.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
          Else
              lab.Position = xlLabelPositionBelow
          End If
          count = count + 1
      Next lab

End Sub
```